# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'method' of VAR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, computer-science

I am using AngularJS to post to my WebAPI (C#/.Net). It was working but I removed my password field from the UserProfile object (because I'm using entity framework and don't want to have the column in that table) and now am passing the password as a string from the interface to the UsersController via posting.

**Problem**:
UsersController never receives the post because the browser throws the error:

**TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'method' of password**

here is my AngularJS code doing the post to the UsersController:

```
var _addUser = function(newUser, password) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    alert('_addUser password is ' + password);
    **//********** password gets here just fine**
    $http.post("/api/v1/users", newUser, password) **// <-- this is where it breaks**
        .then(function(result) {
            //success
            var newlyCreatedUser;
             angular.copy(result.data, newlyCreatedUser);
            _users.splice(0, 0, newlyCreatedUser); 
            deferred.resolve(newlyCreatedUser);
        },
        function () {
            //error
            deferred.reject();
        });

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

**Here is my UsersController method it is supposed to send stuff to:**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]UserProfile newUser, string password)
    {
        if (newUser.Created == default(DateTime))
        {
            newUser.Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        if (_repo.AddUser(newUser, password) 
            && _repo.Save())
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created
                , newUser);
        }

        else
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to not collect the password in a separate string and just tell Entity Framework to ignore the Password class with the [NotMapped] decoration.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Shree, yes it does answer the question. This was Doug's solution to his own problem.